# I wants a service on Grails to send email automatically?

Tags: email, grails, service, automation

I want a service auto starting up when startup server. I wants this service send emails to all customer in database at 8am on Monday, Wednesday and Friday.

Who can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

It would have been great if you had shown some effort but, in the spirit of helping here's how you can approach this problem:

1. Install the Grails [mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail) in your app and try to send one email using it. The docs are pretty straightforward.
2. Then create a Service which has a method that gets the list of customers in your database, e.g., Customer.list() and loops over each record and sends an email.
3. Then Install the [quartz plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz)
4. Then create a Grails Job that calls this service method.
5. Then initialize your job in Bootstrap.groovy like (more about cron expressions [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)):

   NotificationSenderJob.schedule('0 0 8 ? * MON-FRI', null)

and you should be all set to go.

Comment: 2a. Install the quartz plugin

Comment: Thanks @IanRoberts. You should have edited the answer.

Comment: I don't like to edit "fresh" answers from other people, though I might have edited it if I'd come back tomorrow and you hadn't fixed it yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try the above folow.